# Python Read Certain Number of Bytes After Character

Tags: python, parsing, hex, offset

I'm dealing with a character separated hex file, where each field has a particular start code. I've opened the file as 'rb', but I was wondering, after I get the index of the startcode using .find, how do I read a certain number of bytes from this position?
This is how I am loading the file and what I am attempting to do

```
with open(someFile, 'rb') as fileData:
    startIndex = fileData.find('(G')
    data = fileData[startIndex:7]
```

where 7 is the number of bytes I want to read from the index returned by the find function. I am using python 2.7.3

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: what do you see: `print(repr(open('your filename', 'rb').read(10)))`?

Comment: that would read the first 10 bytes of the file

Comment: yes, it would. What do you see? The phrase "hex file" is suspicious -- it might indicate the fundamental misunderstanding on your part of what files are (from the application point of view).

Comment: Do you want to find a byte sequence `bytearray([40, 71])` (two bytes) in the file? Or do you want to find a *text* `u'\u0028\u0047'` (two characters (two Unicode codepoints))? You should know the character encoding that is used to store the text in the file in the latter case

Comment: I should specify, that when I say hex file, I mean this if for a machine to interpret. I understand that you can read bytes from any file, the structure of this file is best described like that. The data is decently nonsense, and the hex code corresponds to characters, but I was asking if I could search on the string representation of the characters as opposed to the hex code for those characters and still have python use the index returned by a find on that, given that some characters are more than one byte.

Comment: if you don't know what character encoding is, read [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)

Comment: Thank you for the reading recommendation, I'll check it out. This subject is a little confusing to me to be honest. I want to find the index in the file and then read several bytes from that position. For example, I want to find the characters '(G' and then read seven bytes of data from that point, as it will be an embedded length.

Comment: @Jacksgrin: Read the link, to understand: *"There Ain't No Such Thing As Plain Text."*  -- you can't find text in a file if you don't know the character encoding. Read, it will save you time.

Comment: I read the link and I believe that the file is in ANSI encoding. I'm using a hex editor to view it and, based on some of the character bytecodes, believe this to be it. That said, I think it would be smart for me to do a find on the bytecode values rather than text representation and edit as a byte string.

Comment: @Jacksgrin: ANSI is not a specific character encoding. Valid examples would be utf-8, utf-16le, cp1252, shift-jis, ASCII, etc. What do you see if you run `locale.getpreferredencoding()`?  There are bytestrings (byte sequences) and Unicode strings (sequences of Unicode codepoints). The former you get if you read a *binary* file (`'rb'` mode), the latter – if you read a *text* file (you should provide the corresponding character encoding). There are no *"character bytecodes"* Don't mix bytes and Unicode strings. Python 2 lets you get away with it (it may perform implicit conversions).

Comment: Its definitely not unicode. Its machine code and I'm told its interpreted as hex. That said there are some 'strings' in this file. Meaning some of the hex translates to words. I believe the best way of doing this is to manipulate purely with hex - ie. search with hex, insert hex etc.

Comment: Also, ASCII extended then, if not ANSI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the position of a substring in a bytestring under python2.7 like this:

```
>>> with open('student.txt', 'rb') as f:
...     data = f.read()
... 
>>> data  # holds the French word for student: élève
'\xc3\xa9l\xc3\xa8ve\n'
>>> len(data)  # this shows we are dealing with bytes here, because "élève\n" would be 6 characters long, had it been properly decoded!
8
>>> len(data.decode('utf-8'))
6
>>> data.find('\xa8')  # continue with the bytestring...
4
>>> bytes_to_read = 3
>>> data[4:4+bytes_to_read]  
'\xa8ve'
```

You can look for the special characters, and for compatibility with Python3k, it's better if you prepend the character with a `b`, indicating these are bytes (in Python2.x, it will work without though):

```
 >>> data.find(b'è')  # in python2.x this works too (unfortunately, because it has lead to a lot of confusion): data.find('è')
3
>>> bytes_to_read = 3
>>> pos = data.find(b'è')
>>> data[pos:pos+bytes_to_read] # when you use the syntax 'n:m', it will read bytes in a bytestring
'\xc3\xa8v'
>>>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. I did mention it is a given, but I wanted to check to see if I am doing it right. First, I am reading binary and storing into a filedata variable and then I am doing a find on the characters that I am looking for, lets say '(G'. I am not using hex code for this (will this work?) and then using the index to do a substring on the filedata variable.

Comment: If you already have it as a string of bytes (python2 or python3, btw?) and you have found a position with `pos = mybytestring.find(some_marker)`, then why not use `mybytestring[pos:pos+bytes_to_read]`?

Comment: Because I was not sure if number that I would put in bytes to read would read characters or bytes. Also didn't know if searching for the actual characters instead of the byte code to use as the start position would work...Will it?

Comment: That all depends on which version of python you are using and if it's not a bytestring whether you have properly encoded your "string". Perhaps you could add this info to your original post, so that we can leave the comments for clarifications.

Comment: @ Oliver -- Apologies, I have added the info for clarification. Sorry, I'm still working on getting good post structure.

Comment: @OliverW.: it does not depend on Python version. File mode `'rb'` specifies that you would read `bytes` on both Python 2 and 3. For compatibility with Python 3, use `b''` literals to specify `bytes`.

Comment: Thank you @J.F.Sebastian, I've incorporated your suggestion about the`b''` syntax. It does make it more clear for those who know what unicode and bytes are.

Comment: don't use non-ascii bytes literals (it is a `SyntaxError` in Python 3. It requires source encoding declaration on Python 2) and it is confusing on any version (the value is ambiguous. It depends on your terminal encoding if you type it in the REPL directly).